# Political world map texture?

Tags: coordinate-system, 3d

What is correct name of texture and/or projection, which is suitable for 3D engines?

I want to apply world map to 3D sphere, but a variety of images found by Google makes me thinks that some of them are incorrect.

I imagine an image of size proportional to 360 x 180 (number of latitude and longitude degrees on the globe). What is the name of this projection?

I don't see this projection here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection because grid should be equi-quadri-lateral on it.

Comment: To map a globe properly you can't use a projection at all. What you want is *geographical coordinates*, like WGS84. As for a texture that covers that SRTM might serve http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/ it's elevation raster. The cells aren't measured in feet or metres they are in arcseconds of the earths' surface. I think that's the question you're asking, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection you describe has *many* names: equirectangular, simple cylindrical, equidistant cylindrical, plate carrée, etc. See [wikipedia's Equirectangular Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection).

Whether this is suitable for use in "3D engines" would require more knowledge of such software.

Comment: If you have some interesting equirectangular maps of the world and wish to render them as though they were globes, you *might* benefit from continuing along the lines of your question. However, you might get better advice if you provide clearer context on your problem: what are you starting with, what should you end up with, what software do you expect to use, etc.